# Eclipse errors on startup

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Sorry if this question is kind of vague.  Let me know if I can provide any additional relevant details.

Basically, every so often (at least once every few weeks), when I open my Eclipse workspace I am greeted with a large number of errors.  It often says that almost every single one of my projects have errors even though they were working just the day before.  I understand that something is getting messed up in the build-path because it gives me errors such as `The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved.`  However, I don't understand why restarting Eclipse would cause this build-path to get messed up.  It also seems fairly common for me to get errors on imports for various Android classes even though I have included the Android SDK in the project.

I guess what I am asking is twofold:

1) Why is this happening and is there anything that I can do to stop this from happening?

2) When this does happen, is there an easy way that I can resolve it?  I know that I can go into the Preferences for an individual project and add libraries to the build-path but I can't figure out how to easily do this for all of my projects at once, and I feel like I'm just trying things until they work, so it would be good to have a more defined procedure for dealing with these sorts of problems.

EDIT:
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Theres a problem with your JDK. Make sure your project is pointing to it! Install it if you dont have it.

Comment: Maybe some write protection of the .classpath file?

Comment: is it possible that the `.classpath` file is getting modified/corrupted?

Comment: I also have the project build target set to Android 4.4.2, but its giving me errors on my imports for all of the Android classes

Comment: First fix your java problem, then worry about android

Comment: well I have no idea what I did, but I cleaned the project (again, I'd already done it several times), and all the errors went away.  But my question still stands: why did this happen to begin with and how can I prevent it?

Comment: I just updated the Platform Tools, so maybe it was that, but they were up-to-date a few days ago so I don't see why I should've gotten all those errors by being one subversion behind

Answer (score 0):

You might need a valid JRE or JDK defined in the Java Build Path of your project.